# How to add git remote repos name repeatedly in jenkins shell?

Tags: git, shell, jenkins

In jenkins shell, I want to add remote repos, but if repos name exist, then I met

```
fatal: remote I-WANT-TO-PUSH already exists.
```

and jenkins aborted unexpectedly.

I want to pseudo code below.

```
if [ ! git remote I-WANT-TO-PUSH exist? ]
  git remote add I-WANT-TO-PUSH http://i-want-to-push.example.com
fi
git push I-WANT-TO-PUSH
```

How to do this?

Edited:(thanks @Nikolay)

below is nearly actual code:

```
o=$(git remote | grep 'pushable')
if [[ $o == '' ]]; then
  hub remote add pushable https://$GH_TOKEN@github.com/foo/bar.git
fi
```

then I got:

```
++ grep pushable
++ git remote
+ o=
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround, I check below:

```
Wipe out workspace before build
```

and always

```
git remote add pushable
```

Answer (score 2):

With this script you'll confirm does list of origins have I-WANT*.git as pushable resource

```
o=$(git remote -v| grep '/I-WANT-TO-PUSH.git (push)')
if [[ $o == '' ]]; then 
 echo "not exists"
else
 echo "exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

easy and lazy solution :P

```
$ git push remote add I-WANT-TO-PUSH 2> /dev/null || echo
```

or

```
$ git push remote add I-WANT-TO-PUSH || echo
```